# Question about the point at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

I have started complex analysis and I am stuck on one definition 'extended complex plane'.Book is saying 'To visualize point at infinity,think of complex plane passing through the equator of a unit sphere centred at 0.To each point z in plane there corresponds exactly one point P on surface of sphere which is obtained by intersection of sphere with line joining point z with north pole N of sphere'.Now my question 
1.Is plane passing through equator of unit sphere means our normal $xy$ plane where $z$ co-ordinate is 0?
2.If so, then all the points in our complex plane inside unit circle should get mapped to north pole N ?
What is going wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Look at the pictures in the Wikipedia article on [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points inside the unit circle are projected onto the emisphere under the plane (that is $Z<0$):

[image]

(credits [Radius of the spherical image of a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/190270/505767))

Refer also to [**Riemann sphere**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere).

Comment: Got it!But still I am not much satisfied with this point at infinity.In our normal complex plane ,if we go much far from origin, we are actually going near infinity, then why this extra point 'point at infinity'.Also this extra point is complex number or just any random point in space.How to think of it intuitively?

Comment: @Believer The best way in my opinion is to refer to the image. When $|z|\to \infty$ in any direction $Z$ approach the north pole of course that point is not reached for any $z$ but we can say that the north pole represents the "point at infinity".

Comment: @Believer Of course we can also see that by an algebraic point of view by the relations $Z=f(z)$ taking the limit as $|z| \to \infty.$

Answer (score 1):

I think that description may be a typo... I think they want to say the following:

Imagine a unit sphere resting on top of the complex plane. For each point $z\in\mathbb{C}$ draw a line segment connecting that point to the "north pole" of the sphere. This line will intersect the sphere in exactly one point besides the north pole, and is distinct for each $z\in\mathbb{C}$. No point will have a line segment that is tangent to the sphere at the north pole, but we may add an extra point to $\mathbb{C}$ that accomplishes this. This is the visualization of the point at infinity.

Comment: And it might be worth pointing out that geometrically it's more like an infinitely large circle! (I do better imagining the complex plane deformed into a sohere, with infinity at the south pole. Then it *is* a point, whise direction from the origin is undefined. **Edit:** I see from the link in the other answer that I'm imagining a Riemann sphere.